# How to break out of an ng-repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-loopback

Following case need to break out from ng-repeat loop

```
<div ng-init="myarr=['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','rst']">
        <div ng-repeat="item in myarr">
             {{item}}
             <ng-container ng-if="item=='pqr'">
                  <!--need to break this loop-->
             </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use a filter on myarr and only loop through the items that you want.

Comment: Don't use ng-init, as clearly documented. Put that code in your controller, and provide the array you really want to loop on to the view. JavaScript is your friend.

Comment: Thank you AndyB for correction my question

Comment: Dear JB Nizet,  it's sample code for understanding and i can't using filter because i have a lot of condition in this loop so i need to Break out looping if my condition is true.

Comment: And? Based on that sample code, my advice is to avoid using ng-init, as documented, and to provide the actual array that the view should iterate on from your controller, in JavaScript.

Comment: Thinking about this all wrong and need to use a filter on the data itself. You can't break `ng-repeat`

Comment: i can't provide this array it is so large and bunch of code can't put here so Loop Breaking is possible or not ?

Comment: charlieftl just said: *You can't break ng-repeat*.

Answer (score 1):

you could work around this by using the index of the `item` in `myarr` like

```
<ng-container ng-if="(myarr.indexOf(item) < myarr.indexOf('pqr'))">
     {{item}}
</ng-container>
```

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjux6g9e/4/)

and if the case is an array of objects

for example if array is

```
`$scope.myarr = [{t:'abc',i:1},
{t:'ghj',i:2},
{t:'rty',i:3},
{t:'qwe',i:4}]`
```

in HTML

```
<ng-container ng-if="(myarr.indexOf(item) < breakVar)">
      {{item.t + ' ' + item.i}} 
</ng-container>
```

and in controller:

```
 $scope.breakVar = $scope.myarr.map(function(x) {return x.i;}).indexOf(3);
```

with object array [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/modar/zuo09v51/)